# AWS S3 - Privacy error when accessing file from link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working with a team that is using S3 to host content and they moved from a single bucket for all brands to one bucket for each brand and now we are having trouble when linking to the content from within salesforce site.com page.  When I copy the link from S3 as HTTPS, I get a >"Your connection is >not private, Attackers might be trying to steal your information from >spiritxpress.s3.varsity.s3.amazonaws.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards)."

I have asked them to compare the settings from the one that is working, and I don't have access to dig into it myself, and we are pretty new to this as well so thought I would see if there were any known paths to walk down.  The ID and Key have not changed and I can access the content via CyberDuck, it just is not loading when reached via a link.

Let me know if additional information is needed and I will provide as quickly as I can.

[EDIT] the bucket naming convention they are using is all lowercase and meets convention guidelines as well, but it seems strange to me they way it is structured as they have named the bucket "brandname.s3.companyname" and when copying the link it comes across as "https://brandname.s3.company.s3.amazonaws.com/directory/filename" where the other bucket was being rendered as "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/......

Comment: I was playing around with a few things and when I go into the web console and copy the link to the file and paste into the site, the file opens as expected. but is a very long URL and we don't want to  ask the users to do that and would rather do it through the S3 FTP tool and copy the short url. With that I am assuming there is some security/permissons being missed that is blocking the file from being loaded via the reqular link

Answer (score 13):

Whoever made this change has failed to account for the way wildcard certificates work in HTTPS.

Requests to S3 using HTTPS are greeted with a certificate identifying itself as "*.s3[-region].amazonaws.com" and in order for the browser to consider this to be valid when compared to the link you're hitting, there cannot be any dots in the part of the hostname that matches the `*` offered by the cert.  Bucket names with dots are valid, but they cannot be used on the left side of "s3[-region].amazonaws.com" in the hostname unless you are willing and able to accept a certificate that is deemed invalid... they can only be used as the first element of the path.

The only way to make dotted bucket names and S3 native wildcard SSL to work together is the other format: `https://s3[-region].amazonaws.com/example.dotted.bucket.name/...`.

If your bucket isn't in us-standard, you likely need to use the region in the hostname, so that the request goes to the correct endpoint, e.g. `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example.dotted.bucket.name/path...` for a bucket in us-west-2 (Oregon).  Otherwise S3 may return an error telling you that you need to use a different endpoint (and the endpoint they provide in the error message will be valid, but probably not the one you're wanting for SSL).

This is a limitation on how SSL certificates work, not a limitation in S3.

Answer (score -4):

Okay, it appears it did boil down to some permissions that were missed and we were able to get the file to display as expected.  Other issues are present, but the present one is resolved so marking as answered.

Comment: Can you please explain setting you did?